# When loading Angular JS component, I'm getting typeerror-angular-lowercase-is-not-a-function

Tags: angularjs, angular, typeerror, lowercase, angular-hybrid

I have a hybrid project with both Angular 9 and Angular JS. When loading the Angular JS component, in getting the below error in console. typeerror-angular-lowercase-is-not-a-function.
Please advise

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular helper - lowercase like pipe or something, it is deprecated. You should change for code to use standard js toLowerCase(). Since you have not attached any snippet or code sample, this is the only way to answer.

You can check this here:

[Angular - fix(Angular): remove angular.lowercase and angular.uppercase](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/1daa4f2231a89ee88345689f001805ffffa9e7de#diff-1d54c5f722aebc473dbe96f836ddf974)